# sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]

Tags: python, asp.net-core, iis, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

Getting an error while calling python script from asp.net core webapi. If i ran python code using IDLE 3.7(64bit) then it is working fine, but while calling same py file from .net application it throws an error. one more thing it is fine if i directly run the code from visual studio, error only comes on server where i have hosted app in IIS.

Error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D://Ainfonix2.0//PythonService//preproc//xmain.py", line 39, in <module>
    doc_list_sp = sp.spexecute(sp1) #document list
  File "D:\Ainfonix2.0\PythonService\preproc\CL\Stored_Procedure.py", line 27, in spexecute
   connection = engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2188, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2162, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1476, in handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 265, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 248, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2158, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 342, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 788, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 529, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1193, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 66, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 249, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 1190, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 347, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 474, in __init__
    self.__connect(first_connect_check=True)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 671, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 106, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 412, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Python code sample is as below.

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://py:py@py/?charset')
```

.net code sample as below.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pyExecutableFile)
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = false,
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", pyFile, arguments)
            };

            var res = process.Start();
            if (res)
            {
                result = true;
                pythonServiceError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();
                process.Close();
            }
```

Asp.net core -2.0
Python - 3.7

Comment: Please check your system. if it is 32-bit then IIS cannot find your driver or the DSN. and  ensure you are connecting to a system DSN and not a user DSN.  A user DSN is per logged in user and IIS will not be using the same user than you.

Comment: @samwu, I checked and system is 64 bit only. Also I have added system dan and checked.still no luck. Could you pls tell me what else possibility can be. !

Comment: You can also check the spelling of the DSN matches that of the configured DSN in the ODBC Administrator. One letter wrong is all it takes for a DSN to be mismatched.[Here is an article that may provide some additional details](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/3352?q=%22Data%20source%20name%20not%20found%20and%20no%20default%20driver%20specified%22&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1&utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=support-kb&utm_term=alch&utm_content=jdbc&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=support-kb&utm_term=alch&utm_content=odbc).